# How to specify array index in ModelState when validating custom validation attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I have the following model (simplified version):

```
public class AddZoneModel
{    
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the zone.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the minimum of optimal disponibilities.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [DisponibilityCollection]
    public int[] Disponibilities { get; set; }
}
```

The array of ints should have exactly 12 (monthly) values, each value within a range taken from the database.
This is validated in the following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class DisponibilityCollectionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var values = value as int[];

        if (values == null || values.Length != 12)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("The specified object is not a collection of 12 integers", new string[] { validationContext.MemberName });
        }

        using (AdminRepository db = new AdminRepository())
        {
            ValidationRangesModel ranges = db.GetValidationRanges();

            int min = ranges.MinimumDisponibilidad;
            int max = ranges.MaximumDisponibilidad;

            var errorMembers = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
            {
                if (values[i] < min || values[i] > max)
                {
                    errorMembers.Add(string.Format("Disponibilities[{0}]", i));
                }
            }

            if (errorMembers.Count > 0)
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Disponibilidad should be between {0} and {1}", min, max), errorMembers);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

If the ModelState is not valid, my API returns a JSON object with a parsed version of the model state errors.

Problem is that the validated array does not show which item was invalid.
The ModelState contains only one message for the array property itself `"Disponibilities"`.
This breaks error validation, as I have 12 textboxes.
(Actually I have a lot more than 12 textboxes, because the pattern repeats itself. This is simplified)

How do I customize the property names so they will be like "Disponibilities[2]" or "Disponibilities_2_" so I can recognize the appropriate controls with JS and show validation errors?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897281/validating-multiple-textboxes-using-jqueryvalidation-in-mvc

Comment: Thanks for the editing and response.
This doesn't solve the issue when server validation returnes error.
Or am I missing something?

Comment: The second parameter of ValidationResult are memeber names, it does not take objects. If you want a more flexible way, you can implement `IValidatableObject`, and `IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)` does return a collection, then you can accurate errors in collection, and put the index into each error message.